# HTML/CSS link doesn't work probably

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have 3 links in my code but only two are working probably, why?

```
<div id="welcome-text-2" class="welcome-text">
    <p>
        <b>boldtext</b><br>
        text <a href="#">link</a>.<br>
        Text<a href="#">här</a>.<br>
        Text<a href="#">Link</a>.<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome-text {
    height: 240px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -5px black;
}

#welcome-text-2 {
    margin-top: 400px;
}

    #welcome-text-2 b {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

    #welcome-text-2 p {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 7px;
    }

.welcome-text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
}

    .welcome-text a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

the last two links work when :hover'd. But the first one doesn't. I also tried to add a link in the first row but it didn't appear.

Comment: we need some more explanation. what are you expecting from these links that doenst("probably") work?

Comment: I think he meant the word properly, not probably.

Comment: Works for me in latest Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jL2Eb/  Can you be more clear about the problem?

Comment: @Danny - aaaah, I think you're properly right...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are beginning to learn HTML/ CSS.

The markup above works correct. Did you clear the browser-cache? There could old styles/ markup beeing cached.

[http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache)

Answer (score 0):

The Code Provided does work.

Adding onto what @ilovemondays said, Please make sure your links are updated if your stylesheet is external.